# Когда поднято VPN соединение, на клиенте любой ресурс в интернет становится недоступен

Tags: vpn, openvpn

Сервер OpenVPN поднят на Ubuntu. Конфигурация сервера (стандартная):

```
port 1194
proto tcp
dev tun
sndbuf 0
rcvbuf 0
ca ca.crt
cert server.crt
key server.key
dh dh.pem
tls-auth ta.key 0
topology subnet
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
keepalive 10 120
cipher AES-128-CBC
comp-lzo
user nobody
group nogroup
persist-key
persist-tun
status openvpn-status.log
verb 3
crl-verify crl.pem
```

В качестве клиента Windows. Конфигурация (тоже стандартная):

```
client
dev tun
proto tcp
sndbuf 0
rcvbuf 0
remote *ip адрес сервера* 1194
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
remote-cert-tls server
cipher AES-128-CBC
comp-lzo
setenv opt block-outside-dns
key-direction 1
verb 3
```

Проблема заключается в том, что когда поднято VPN соединение, на клиенте любой ресурс в интернет становится недоступен. Команда ping говорит что не удалось обнаружить имя. При отключении VPN все приходит в норму.

Что нужно настроить?

Answer (score 0):

Советую попробовать мой набор скриптов для установки и настройки https://github.com/emobortnik/easy-openvpn

С помощью этих скриптов вы сможете настроить свой собственный VPN-сервер за несколько кликов, даже если вы раньше не использовали OpenVPN.

После выполнения сценария вы можете запустить его снова, чтобы добавить больше пользователей (сертификатов), проверить список пользователей, удалить некоторые из них или даже полностью удалить OpenVPN.

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет. [Как написать хороший ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)